# Gradle dependency resolved in the wrong repository

Tags: gradle

I have declared my `MavenLocal` as a repository of the Gradle project I'm trying to build:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
    }
}
```

That maven cache already contains artifact, including the artifact `C:\Users\212636336\.m2\repository\com\jetbrains\intellij\idea\ideaIU\2016.2.5` (pom and zip). If I add the dependancy in another *Maven* project, it is properly loaded:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jetbrains.intellij.idea</groupId>
            <artifactId>ideaIU</artifactId>
            <version>2016.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

Now, I run Gradle in debug *and offline* mode `-d build`. I get some artifacts properly resolved from MavenLocal, like:

```
10:40:17.095 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2 using repositories [MavenLocal, Gradle Central Plugin Repository]
10:40:17.095 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/C:/Users/212636336/.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.pom
10:40:17.096 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/C:/Users/212636336/.m2/repository/classworlds/classworlds/1.1-alpha-2/classworlds-1.1-alpha-2.jar
10:40:17.096 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] Metadata file found for module 'classworlds:classworlds:1.1-alpha-2' in repository 'MavenLocal'.
```

But, one of the artifact seems to be looked into another repository, and obviously, not found (as it's offline, and I must be offline for "security network access reason" [let's not challenge that...]):

```
10:40:17.216 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIU:2016.2.5 using repositories [maven]
```

It seems to try resolving this in a "maven" repository, instead of "MavenLocal" (and Gradle repo).

How can I force this dependency (and all dependencies if some other later on fails too) to use `MavenLocal` repo only?

More log lines around the quoted one:

```
15:09:50.096 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on proj remapped class cache for 7rwuz20xh772cpzs4giq79qsx (C:\Users\212636336\.gradle\caches\4.8\scripts-remapped\build_18iha3p23efgp2pj2dagsrxjv\7rwuz20xh772cpzs4giq79qsx\projae602bbdde29eee3c9aedf6517e613d1).
15:09:50.097 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on proj remapped class cache for 7rwuz20xh772cpzs4giq79qsx (C:\Users\212636336\.gradle\caches\4.8\scripts-remapped\build_18iha3p23efgp2pj2dagsrxjv\7rwuz20xh772cpzs4giq79qsx\projae602bbdde29eee3c9aedf6517e613d1).
15:09:50.097 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on proj remapped class cache for 7rwuz20xh772cpzs4giq79qsx (C:\Users\212636336\.gradle\caches\4.8\scripts-remapped\build_18iha3p23efgp2pj2dagsrxjv\7rwuz20xh772cpzs4giq79qsx\projae602bbdde29eee3c9aedf6517e613d1).
15:09:50.262 [QUIET] [system.out] add repo
15:09:50.262 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'phpinspectionsea''
15:09:50.262 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'phpinspectionsea'' completed
15:09:50.263 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 2.809 secs
10:40:17.194 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring IntelliJ IDEA gradle plugin
10:40:17.195 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring patch plugin.xml task
10:40:17.195 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring prepare IntelliJ sandbox task
10:40:17.196 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring prepare IntelliJ sandbox task
10:40:17.196 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring plugin verification task
10:40:17.197 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring run IntelliJ task
10:40:17.198 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring building IntelliJ IDEA plugin task
10:40:17.199 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring publishing IntelliJ IDEA plugin task
10:40:17.199 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring IntelliJ resources task
10:40:17.200 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring IntelliJ compile tasks
10:40:17.202 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin org.jetbrains.intellij to root project 'phpinspectionsea''
10:40:17.202 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin org.jetbrains.intellij to root project 'phpinspectionsea'' completed
10:40:17.203 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin com.palantir.git-version to root project 'phpinspectionsea'' started
10:40:17.206 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin com.palantir.git-version to root project 'phpinspectionsea''
10:40:17.207 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin com.palantir.git-version to root project 'phpinspectionsea'' completed
10:40:17.211 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'phpinspectionsea''
10:40:17.211 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to root project 'phpinspectionsea'' completed
10:40:17.212 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 0.379 secs
10:40:17.212 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Configuring IntelliJ IDEA dependency
10:40:17.212 [INFO] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Using IDE from remote repository
10:40:17.212 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Adding IntelliJ IDEA repository: https://cache-redirector.jetbrains.com/www.jetbrains.com/intellij-repository/releases
10:40:17.213 [DEBUG] [org.jetbrains.intellij.IntelliJPlugin] Adding IntelliJ IDEA dependency
10:40:17.213 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of :detachedConfiguration1' started
10:40:17.214 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver] Resolving configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'
10:40:17.215 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.ResolvedArtifactCaches] Creating new in-memory cache for repo 'maven' [73520db826dde63c67f6b3554017db77].
10:40:17.215 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.builder.DependencyGraphBuilder] Visiting configuration com.kalessil.phpStorm.phpInspectionsEA:phpinspectionsea:unspecified(detachedConfiguration1).
10:40:17.216 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIU:2016.2.5 using repositories [maven]
10:40:17.217 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.oldresult.TransientConfigurationResultsBuilder] Flushing resolved configuration data in Binary store in C:\Users\212636336\AppData\Local\Temp\gradle3411383493479648862.bin. Wrote root 2.
10:40:17.219 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of :detachedConfiguration1'
10:40:17.219 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve dependencies of :detachedConfiguration1' completed
10:40:17.220 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Configure project :'
10:40:17.221 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 417: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
10:40:17.222 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Configure project :' completed
10:40:17.222 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Configure build'
10:40:17.223 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.SynchronizedDispatchConnection] thread 417: dispatching class org.gradle.launcher.daemon.protocol.BuildEvent
10:40:17.224 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Configure build' completed
10:40:17.224 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:40:17.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:40:17.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] 
10:40:17.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:40:17.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] A problem occurred configuring root project 'phpinspectionsea'.
10:40:17.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter] > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
10:40:17.225 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]    > Could not resolve com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIU:2016.2.5.
10:40:17.226 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]      Required by:
10:40:17.226 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]          project :
10:40:17.226 [ERROR] [org.gradle.internal.buildevents.BuildExceptionReporter]       > No cached version of com.jetbrains.intellij.idea:ideaIU:2016.2.5 available for offline mode.
```

(it seems like IntelliJ IDEA IU adds its "maven" repo and overrides the ones I've set in the `build.gradle` file of the project; how could I avoid that?)

Comment: Maybe we need more information to find the problem. However, I have one guess. You declared the repository in the `buildscript` block. Have you declared it at the outer scope as well? The `buildscript` block is only for dependencies of the build script. Dependencies for the project are resolved using the repositories declared at the outer scope.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine if the mavenLocal repo is declared. I wonder if the IdeaPlugin you use is doing something nasty, like removing that maven local repo temporally. You could check and trace changes to your repositories by using these hooks:

```
repositories.whenObjectAdded { repo ->
   ...
}

repositories.whenObjectRemoved { repo ->
   ...
}
```

Comment: I've added these with `print "add repo"` instead of ... (and `print "remove repo"`) and I got 1 "add repo" in my console (see edition) but no "remove repo". Is there a way I can use these hooks to block IdeaPlugin from adding its own repositories (and leave mine instead)?

Comment: project.repositories is a mutual list. so you can use standard methods to remove items. one example can be found in the gradle documentation for the use of init scripts. see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:init_script_plugins